# CentOS 6.5 - bash: service: command not found

Tags: root, centos-6

So I can't type `service` on my CentOS 6.5 server.
I'm logged in as root.
When typing `service` I get this error:

> bash: service: command not found

I have also tried to type `sudo service`, but with no luck.
And then I get this error:

> sudo: service: command not found

Comment: in my case, `cd /sbin/; ./service` gave me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discovered in the extended discussion through comments, your system is broken. I suggest reinstalling the system completely or at least the broken packages.

To have `/sbin/service` again run `yum reinstall initscripts`.

I don't recommend it, but if you want to reinstall all the packages that fail verification, run:

```
yum reinstall $(rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}\n' -a | while read rpm; do rpm -V $rpm >/dev/null || echo $rpm; done)
```

Take note that even a modified configuration file or changed `mtime` might trigger a reinstall. Though the new configuration files should come up with the `.rpmnew` extension if you changed the original.

Comment: I think I would be better just reinstalling the whole system. Do you have an idea how the problem occured? (My last command before it happend was tmux a -t scripts and now today when I logged in I did yum install httpd and yum install php-mysql and then service httpd start, and then I could not)

Comment: Maybe someone broke into your server. Perhaps you were running a vulnerable PHP application. Have a look at [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/q/218005/4276) from Server Fault. Anyway don't forget to save the logs before reinstalling for further analysis.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help so fare. I have not ran any PHP applications. Only java jars. I dont know if they can make trouble.

Comment: The Java browser plugin is infamous for its security vulnerabilities, but I'm not familiar with its server side if that's your case.

Answer (score 7):

The `service` command resides in the `sbin` directory - make sure it exists at `/sbin/service`

If you are root, then according to this mailing list, you may need to make sure it's on your path:
[Centos5 - Service Command Not Present](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2007-August/042974.html).

You may also check out a similar function called `chkconfig`, since it can activate services as well. [CentOS - chkconfig](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-services-chkconfig.html)

The links attached are for CentOS 5, but they don't seem to differ in CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding /sbin to my PATH in CentOS 5.2

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: sbin should only be in the path of the root user.